# Android - re-execute only failed asynctask which runs in parallel

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm new to android studio, I just want to ask, is there any possible to re-execute only the failed async task which runs in parallel?

For example, I have 50 photos to be "download" from my database through PHP, during the multiple parallel asynctask execution, one of the image did not downloaded(image get drawable is null), how am i gonna to run the particular failed image only, without re-execute whole thing again?

Comment: Do you have some id's of Images to identify them??

Comment: I don't actually have id for them, but i capture their position in ArrayList, I have multiple tabs, each tabs will have different photo.size() , so, that means position is not applicable to identify which image is lost.